# Smartband2 & Lifelog shutdown

Tags: c#, json, sony-smartwatch

How to access data from SonySmartBand2?

Everything works fine with the internal smartband2 app and it reads the step and everything. However we want to access the step data and upload to a website. Previously we used sony LifeLog API to do it, but as it is has been shut down, that is no longer an option.

We considered using the Google FIT, but it won't read the data from the smartband, even though it says it is connected in the Google Fit App.

So how do we fix our old website?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to share the data correctly with Google Fit from the Smartband 2. You can read more about that in this post:
[Can't get heart rate data from google fit API with smartband 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36308062/cant-get-heart-rate-data-from-google-fit-api-with-smartband-2)

You can read more about how to pull Smartband 2 data from Google fit here:
https://developer.sony.com/2015/09/10/use-smartband-2-sensor-data-for-innovative-android-and-ios-applications/